# Issue with geocoder using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

I have a model called room and in the show view I want to display other rooms nearby.

**show.html.erb**

```
<div>
   <% for room in @room.nearbys(10) %>
   <%= image_tag room.photos[0].image.url(:medium) %>
   <%= link_to room.listing_name, room %><br>
   (<%= room.distance.round(2) %> miles away)
   <% end %>
</div>
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161006135631) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_photos_on_room_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "listing_name"
    t.string   "accommodation_type"
    t.integer  "persons"
    t.integer  "property"
    t.integer  "living_area"
    t.text     "rooms_total"
    t.text     "features_short"
    t.string   "pets"
    t.string   "smoking"
    t.string   "check_in"
    t.string   "check_out"
    t.string   "location"
    t.text     "distance"
    t.text     "features_long"
    t.text     "detailed_description"
    t.text     "house_rules"
    t.string   "address"
    t.text     "video"
    t.integer  "nightly_price"
    t.integer  "hourly_price"
    t.text     "detailed_price"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "photos", "rooms"
end
```

I have used the [RailsCasts Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?autoplay=true) for orientation.
Unfortunately I am getting this Error:

[image]

**How can I make this work?**

Any hints for a solution are very appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb file.

Comment: Sure I have edited my post with the schema.rb information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rooms` table have column **distance**.

And your SQL query is creating an alias **distance**.(`AS DISTANCE`).

Hence PostgreS is raising ambiguous column error.

This query is generated by gem which you are using I recommend you to change the column name of column **distance** to something else like **my_distance** or something which will not conflict with the query generated by gem.

Comment: This worked for me thanks allot! Can you please tell me how did you know that my SQL query was creating an alias DISTANCE? Maybe I can figure out this next time by myself if I know how you figured this one out! Thanks ;)

Comment: I saw it in the screen shot you posted. there is a sql query which has **AS DISTANCE** clause.